# Create popup window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create popup window.
But I have some problem: 
Popup window should disappear after click outside it. But in my solution popup disappear when I click inside it.
Here is my code:

```
<div class="popup__show">Click Me</div>
<div class="popup__container">
  <div class="popup">
    hellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohello
  </div>
</div>
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.popup__show').click(function() {
        $('.popup__container').show();
    });
    $('.popup__container').click(function() {
        $('.popup__container').hide();
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fw1d59Lz/ - fiddle

Comment: You can use bootstrap which closes automatically when u click outside popup without any additional code

Comment: thanks, but I need solution without bootstrap)

Comment: Well...without any additional code other than Bootstrap.  :)

Answer (score 1):

You can stop the propagation of the event when a click on the popup happens:

```
$('.popup').click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fw1d59Lz/1/

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your jquery, and you're good to go -

```
  $('.popup').click(function(evt) {
     evt.stopPropagation();
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Events bubble up. So when you click on `.popup`, `.popup__container` will hear it unless you stop it. To do that, call `stopPropagation()` on the event.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.popup__show').click(function(e) {
      $('.popup__container').show();
    });
    $('.popup').click(function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
    });
    $('.popup__container').click(function(e) {
      $('.popup__container').hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this might help you

```
$('.popup__container').click(function(e) {
if (e.target !== this)
return;
$('.popup__container').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jqueryUI Dialog.

https://jqueryui.com/dialog/

you can then write your custom events to open and close the dialog whenever you want.